# ord map from a local field to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: class-field-theory, local-field

I'm reading J. Milne's notes on class field theory and near in the section of the chapter on local CFT he speaks of an exact sequence
$$1 \to U_L \to L^{\times} \xrightarrow{\textrm{ord}_L} \mathbb{Z} \to 1.$$
Here $L$ is a local field and $U_L$ is the unit group of the ring of integers of $L$. Maybe I missed something but as far as I can tell there is no explanation of what the map $\textrm{ord}_L$ is. Can someone fill me in? Thanks.

Comment: It's the exponent of the power of a prime element of $\mathcal O_L$ in the factorization of elements of $L^\times$.  Take $L = \mathbf Q_p$: this ${\rm ord}_L$ is the $p$-adic valuation ${\rm ord}_p$: if $x \in \mathbf Q_p^\times$ we can write $x = p^nu$ for a unique integer $n$ and unit $u \in \mathbf Z_p^\times$. The exponent $n$ is ${\rm ord}_p(x)$.

Comment: @KCd Perfect. Thanks!